# Updating a table's rows if they meet a criteria that depends on the values of other tables

Tags: sql, h2

Learning SQL with an H2 database.

**CLOTHES** TABLE:

```
-------------
| ID | TYPE |
-------------
|  1 | Shirt|
|  2 | Shirt|
|  3 | Pants|
|  4 | Pants|
|  5 | Pants|
|  6 | Hat  |
|  7 | Hat  |
-------------
```

**INVENTORY** TABLE:

```
-----------------------
| CLOTHING_ID | USING |
-----------------------
|  1          | TRUE  |
|  1          | TRUE  |
|  1          | TRUE  |
|  2          | TRUE  |
|  3          | TRUE  |
|  3          | TRUE  |
-----------------------
```

---

I want to `SET USING=FALSE` all entries in `INVENTORY` that correspond to clothes of type `SHIRT`. In this case, the first, second, third and fourth rows are (because these entries have an `ID` of `1` or `2`, which corresponds to clothes of type `SHIRT` in the `CLOTHES` table). So we got:

```
-----------------------
| CLOTHING_ID | USING |
-----------------------
|  1          | FALSE |
|  1          | FALSE |
|  1          | FALSE |
|  2          | FALSE |
|  3          | TRUE  |
|  3          | TRUE  |
-----------------------
```

I can do this by iterating each row in `INVENTORY`, take its `CLOTHING_ID`, then check in `CLOTHES` for a row with such ID, and check if its type is `SHIRT`. If it is, I can set `USING=FALSE`.

That's several steps. Is this possible to achieve this in a single query instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with an `INNER JOIN` query if you know what IDs you want to update

```
UPDATE INVENTORY a
INNER JOIN CLOTHES b
ON a.ID = b.CLOTHING_ID
SET b.`USING` = 'FALSE'
WHERE a.ID IN(1,2)
```

Or if you want to update where `TYPE = Shirt`

```
UPDATE INVENTORY a
INNER JOIN CLOTHES b
ON a.ID = b.CLOTHING_ID
SET b.`USING` = 'FALSE'
WHERE a.TYPE = 'Shirt'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub-query

```
UPDATE INVENTORY SET USING = 'FALSE'
WHERE CLOTHING_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM CLOTHES WHERE TYPE = 'Shirt')
```